# Display selected checkbox in Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Users want to select maximum 5 checkboxes and the values should display in the textarea. Validation is working fine and the values are coming to textarea. But when I click more than 5 checkboxes, sixth value is coming to textarea. Please check the below code and help me to fix.

If I select four or five checkboxes those values should be displayed in the textarea. Currently it display more than selected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('label.chkskillsedit>input[type=checkbox].hid').on('change', function(evt) {
        if ($('label.chkskillsedit>input[type=checkbox]:checked').length <= 5) {
            $(this).parent('label').toggleClass('highlightcheckboxedit', this.checked);

            function fullskilledit() {
                var allValsedit = [];
                $('label.chkskillsedit :checked').each(function() {
                    allValsedit.push($(this).val());
                });
                $('.txtValueshwskilledit').val(allValsedit);
            };
            $(function() {
                $('.chkskillsedit>input.hid').click(fullskilledit);
                fullskilledit();
            });
        } else {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
            $(this).parent('label').removeClass('highlightcheckboxedit');
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color highlightcheckboxedit">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="51" checked>Architect</label><br>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color ">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="52">Building Designer</label><br>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color ">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="53">Draftsman</label><br>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color highlightcheckboxedit">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="54" checked>Interior Designer</label><br>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color ">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="55">Landscape Designer</label><br>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color ">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="56">MEP Designer</label><br>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color highlightcheckboxedit">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="57" checked>Restoration Architect</label><br>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color ">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="58">Surveyor</label><br>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color ">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="59">Sustainable Designer</label><br>
    <br>
    <textarea cols="50" class="txtValueshwskilledit" name="skills" value="">51,54,57</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call

```
$(function() {
   $('.chkskillsedit>input.hid').click(fullskilledit);
   fullskilledit();
  });
```

Both If and else condition in `if ($('label.chkskillsedit>input[type=checkbox]:checked').length <= 5){...}else{....}`

Check below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('label.chkskillsedit>input[type=checkbox].hid').on('change', function(evt) {
        if ($('label.chkskillsedit>input[type=checkbox]:checked').length <= 5) {
          $(this).parent('label').toggleClass('highlightcheckboxedit', this.checked);

            
            $(function() {
                $('.chkskillsedit>input.hid').click(fullskilledit);
                fullskilledit();
            });
        } else {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
            $(this).parent('label').removeClass('highlightcheckboxedit');
            $(function() {
                $('.chkskillsedit>input.hid').click(fullskilledit);
                fullskilledit();
            });
        }
    })
})
function fullskilledit() {
                var allValsedit = [];
                $('label.chkskillsedit :checked').each(function() {
                    allValsedit.push($(this).val());
                });
                $('.txtValueshwskilledit').val(allValsedit);
            };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color highlightcheckboxedit">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="51" checked>Architect</label><br>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color ">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="52">Building Designer</label><br>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color ">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="53">Draftsman</label><br>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color highlightcheckboxedit">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="54" checked>Interior Designer</label><br>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color ">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="55">Landscape Designer</label><br>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color ">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="56">MEP Designer</label><br>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color highlightcheckboxedit">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="57" checked>Restoration Architect</label><br>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color ">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="58">Surveyor</label><br>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color ">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="59">Sustainable Designer</label><br>
    <br>
    <textarea cols="50" class="txtValueshwskilledit" name="skills" value="">51,54,57</textarea>
```

Comment: I upvote you and aprroved as answer. Consider upvote if this question is deserve :P

Answer (score 0):

Counting starts from 0 in `programming` so you need to use `< 5`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('label.chkskillsedit>input[type=checkbox].hid').on('change', function(evt) {
        if ($('label.chkskillsedit>input[type=checkbox]:checked').length < 5) {
            $(this).parent('label').toggleClass('highlightcheckboxedit', this.checked);

            function fullskilledit() {
                var allValsedit = [];
                $('label.chkskillsedit :checked').each(function() {
                    allValsedit.push($(this).val());
                });
                $('.txtValueshwskilledit').val(allValsedit);
            };
            $(function() {
                $('.chkskillsedit>input.hid').click(fullskilledit);
                fullskilledit();
            });
        } else {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
            $(this).parent('label').removeClass('highlightcheckboxedit');
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color highlightcheckboxedit">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="51" checked>Architect</label><br>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color ">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="52">Building Designer</label><br>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color ">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="53">Draftsman</label><br>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color highlightcheckboxedit">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="54" checked>Interior Designer</label><br>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color ">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="55">Landscape Designer</label><br>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color ">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="56">MEP Designer</label><br>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color highlightcheckboxedit">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="57" checked>Restoration Architect</label><br>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color ">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="58">Surveyor</label><br>
<label class="chkskillsedit cursor1 backgroundcolor2-color ">
    <input class="hid" name="fr_skills" type="checkbox" value="59">Sustainable Designer</label><br>
    <br>
    <textarea cols="50" class="txtValueshwskilledit" name="skills" value="">51,54,57</textarea>
```

Comment: In your answer, I selected five values those values are displaying in textarea. But only four checkboxes got checked. Please check five checkboxes and see the output. I want to display five checkboxes checked and five values in textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `if` condition like this

```
if ($('label.chkskillsedit>input[type=checkbox]:checked').length <= 4) {
```

because when you click on it, it gets checked and then it checkes the if condition. So before the 6th one gets checked and added to textarea, we need to stop that.

Comment: In your answer, I selected five values those values are displaying in textarea. But only four checkboxes got checked. Please check five checkboxes and see the output. I want to display five checkboxes checked and five values in textarea.

Comment: ok , let me check. Its happening the same with the other answers who suggested to use < 5 in condition.